# Angular 4 Timer up ticking too fast

Tags: angular, typescript, timer

I'm trying to create a simple timer in Angular 4 that will up tick each second, but when the following code is run it ticks up way too quickly.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-clock',
  templateUrl: './clock.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./clock.component.css']
})
export class ClockComponent implements OnInit {

  timer: number = 0;

  constructor() {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  timeIt() {
    this.timer++;
  }

  upTick() {
    return setInterval(() => {
      this.timeIt()
    }, 1000);
  }


}
```

// HTML

```
<p>
{{ upTick() }}
<button 
    type="submit" 
    (click)="startStop()">Start/Stop
</button>
</p>
```

Implementing this code in JavaScript using the setInterval() function alone with the parameter timeIt() and 1000 works for each second, not sure what is going wrong here in TypeScript

Comment: Each call  to  `upTick` starts an interval timer. And `upTick` will be called multiple times by Angular when the template is rendered, so you have multiple, concurrent interval timers running.

Comment: That makes sense, is there a way to update the timer variable in the TypeScript file, and then pass { timer } in the html file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @cartant stated in the comments, angular templates is rendered multiple times.

So you only need to have only one interval running at a time.

`setInterval()` returns an id so that you can handle it.

Modifying your code a bit I ended up with this

```
@Component({
    selector: 'main',
    template: `
   <div>
    {{timer}}
    <button (click)="startStop()">Start/Stop</button>
   </div>
    `
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

    timer : number = 0;
    intervalId : number;

    constructor() {
    }


    start() {
      this.intervalId = setInterval(() => {
        this.timeIt()
      }, 1000);
    }

    stop() {
       clearInterval(this.intervalId);
       this.intervalId = -1;
    }

    startStop() {
      if(this.intervalId == -1) {
        this.start();
      }  else {
        this.stop();
      }
    }

    timeIt() {
     this.timer++;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
      this.start();
    }
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Mu1k05WXHhijWDjahd0Y?p=preview